# android how to avoid close of Toolbar's SearchView EditText line on UI update?

Tags: android, user-interface, focus, searchview

I have a SearchView in my Toolbar for a RecyclerView list of CardViews and they are saved in a Room database.  I filter the list with search text via the SearchView and then left-swipe one of the returned Cards to delete it from the database.  The UI updates properly to show any remaining filtered CardViews.

Problem is when I click "x", the close button that I set up to the right of the search EditText line.  The filtered list disappears correctly after the left-swipe to delete the filtered card and the UI updates the new list of the remaining CardViews in the database correctly.  However, during the update of the UI, the search EditText line and the "X" close button are destroyed and the Toolbar returns to showing the default state for the SearchView that I set up, which is to show the search icon as iconified.

However, I would like to keep the search EditText line open, clear the search text and keep the "x" close button to the right of the EdixtText line after the UI is updated.

I tried adding the below code snippets to the mSearchView, the searchItem and the mSearchEditText variables, to try to re-open the search EditText line after the UI update, with no luck:

- .setIconified(false);
- .performClick();
- .expandActionView();
- .requestFocus();

I also put the ViewModel update for the Room database in a background thread with an ExecutorService and then tried to update the UI and clear the search EditText line on the main thread, after the background thread had completed.
But the search icon as iconified was still returned.

So what am I missing?  How can I achieve?

**MainActivity.java**

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainactiv_menu, menu);
        searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);

        if (cardsAdapter != null && cardsAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
        }

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
        MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        if (searchItem != null) {

            mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new SearchViewFocusListener(searchItem));
            if (mSearchView != null) {

                mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
                mSearchEditText = mSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
                mSearchEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
                mSearchEditText.setMaxLines(1);
                ImageView closeButton = mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
                closeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                    // gets the data from the Room database.
                    mQuickcardViewModel.loadFullList();  
                    // reload the database data in to the RecyclerView Adapter.  This destroys 
                    // the search EditText line for the SearchView and also destroys the "x" close 
                    //  button and the search icon re-appears. 
                    cardsAdapter.reloadFullList(mQuickcards);  
                    // Clear the current search text so the member can enter different search text.
                    // This is not working as the UI shows the search icon as iconified.
                    mSearchView.setQuery("",false);
                });
```

**mainactiv_menu.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:title="@string/search_title"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"  />

        <item android:id="@+id/action_new"
            android:title="@string/action_new"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
            tools:targetApi="o"
            android:tooltipText="Add a quickcard"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            app:showAsAction="always"  />


        <item android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
            android:title="@string/action_overflow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
            android:orderInCategory="3"
            app:showAsAction="always" >

            <menu>
                
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/number_of_cards"
                    android:title=""
                    app:showAsAction="always" />

            </menu>

        </item>

    </menu>
```

Comment: last time i worked with searchView and toolbar i got so frustrated and decided to use custom layout for that which took way less time

Answer (score 1):

code:
MainActivity.java
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainactiv_menu, menu);
searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);

if (cardsAdapter != null && cardsAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
}

SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

if (searchItem != null) {

    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new SearchViewFocusListener(searchItem));
    if (mSearchView != null) {

        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        mSearchEditText = mSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        mSearchEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        mSearchEditText.setMaxLines(1);
        ImageView closeButton = mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            // gets the data from the Room database.
            mQuickcardViewModel.loadFullList();  
            // reload the database data in to the RecyclerView Adapter.  This destroys 
            // the search EditText line for the SearchView and also destroys the "x" close 
            //  button and the search icon re-appears. 
            cardsAdapter.reloadFullList(mQuickcards);  
            // Clear the current search text so the member can enter different search text.
            // This is not working as the UI shows the search icon as iconified.
            mSearchView.setQuery("",false);
        });
```